# How do I plot two grouped (by temperature) dependent variables to a ggplot?

Tags: python, ggplot2

Surely there is a simple solution but I cannot figure it out...

I am trying to plot 2 dependent variables on the sample ggplot plot, grouped by temperature.

I can plot them both separately but not together.

I basically want to plot two concentrations of calcium (from differing equations) depending on 4 constant temperatures and pressure.

FYI:
Tc = temperature (colour group),
PCO2 = pressure (x axis),
Calcium1: concentration using eq 1,
Calcium2: concentration using eq 2

My attempted code looks like this:

(ggplot(data=DCa)

- aes(x="PCO2", y="Calcium1", color="Tc")+ geom_line(aes(group="Tc"))
- aes(x="PCO2", y="Calcium2", color="Tc")
- geom_line(aes(group="Tc"))
- ylim(0.0, 2.0)
- labs(x="PCO$*2$ (atm)", y="[Ca$^{2+}$]$*{app}$ (mmol/L)", color='T $\degree$C')
  )

The output is only showing "Calcium2" results.
[ggplot output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3u4vS.png)

Does anyone know how to show both concentration groups?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide some of your data so others can help you. For tips on asking a good question with a reproducible example of your issue, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: Are you working in `python` or `r`? If you're using {ggplot2} natively in `r` you should tag your question appropriately to get the best help.